Some questions about JUC
public class TestJUC {
    private   int x;
    public void actor1(){

        x = 1;

    }

    public void actor2()  {
       System.out.println(x);
    }
}

If thread A executes actor1 method and thread B executes actor2 method and thread A executes x=1 before thread B starts executing, will thread B always output 1 ?
Is there a visibility problem due to the cpu's storeBuffer and invalidate queue?
If there is a visibility problem is the x variable modified by volatile?

Hardware typically doesn't cause visibility problems. E.g. the store buffer has limited capacity and eventually all the stores will become visible to other CPUs. The main cause of visibility problems is the JIT (compiler); e.g. it could hoist a plain loads/store out of a loop.
When the variable is made volatile, the JIT will ensure that the volatile load/store eventually becomes visible. Keep in mind that the JMM is defined in terms of sequential consistent executions, and for that the real time order is not relevant.

When writing code, it is important to rely on the memory model of the language to make sure your code is sound. For performance reasons, it is extremely helpful to understand how the hardware works, but the hardware memory model isn't a replacement for the language memory model. So in the case of Java, it is critical to understand visibility, atomicity, ordering, and how the happens-before relation is defined. Any explanation that relies on 'flushing cache to memory' is fundamentally flawed.

About MESI: caches typically are linearizable because the effect of a cache interaction will be between the start and completion of the cache coherence request (like a read or write). Linearizability will give you real time ordering and will not cause visibility problems.
The problem is delayed visibility is the CPU itself with its various buffers like the store buffers, out of order execution etc. But the delay isn't infinite... eventually everything will become visible. It is the compiler that messes things up.

Qwee: If you need clarifications to the answers to this question, comment.  Don't just repost the same question.  If you do that, someone will notice that the 2nd question is a duplicate and close it.


If thread A executes actor1 method and thread B executes actor2 method and thread A executes x=1 before thread B starts executing, will thread B always output 1 ?

These terms do not apply. You're not thinking about threads the right way. Specifically, the term 'before' is meaningless here. It's tempting to think about all statements in all threads executing on one JVM as being executed in some order but that's not actually how it works.
Specifically, it is possible to observe something that identifies that statement A ran before statement B, but also observe something that identifies that A ran after B at the same time. This sounds impossible; it is not. In practice the JVM is allowed to re-order things and to give each thread a 'local copy' of a field with no attempt to keep things in order, and when a clash occurs, to pick arbitrary and unspecified solutions to fix the clash (basically, one value just wins; it doesn't have to be the most recent one or the least recent one; the JVM spec doesn't require a JVM to do any such things).
Trivially, your system has more than one core so these statements can run at the exact same time.
Attempting to 'play around with it' to learn does not work; System.out causes all sorts of locks to apply, ruining any attempt to observe. And, all you'd be observing is how your system works today. It does not prove all JVMs work like that, or that it works like that tomorrow.

Is there a visibility problem

No there's a sequencing problem.
The JVM only guarantees that non-timing related observations 'make sense' between any 2 statements that have a 'happens-before' relationship: If A has an official HB relationship relative to B, then B cannot observe any state (other than via timing) as it was before A modified that state. Let's call HB(A, B) the concept: The line A has a happens-before relation to B.
That means:

If HB(A, B) then that does not mean A runs before B. For example, if B doesn't observe anything A is changing the JVM is free to completely ignore HB(A, B) here. That's one of the reasons its a really bad idea to speak about sequencing in absolute terms, trying to determine for every line which one 'runs first'. All you can really speak about is observability.
If you just know, somehow, that X runs before Y, but HB(X, Y) is not established, then X can modify something that Y then nevertheless does not observe. Even if Y runs 3 days later. In other words, if Y is System.out.println(someField) and X is someField = 10, then the println statement can print 0. Even if X ran 3 days earlier. The only way to ensure that it prints 10 is to establish HB(X, Y).
HB is not a negative constraint: If HB(A, B) is not established, then B may still be able to observe A's modifications. It may, or it may not. a JVM is free to do whatever it wants. Your job as programmer is to ensure that the JVM's choice does not matter to the correct execution of your code.

To establish HB, the Java Memory Model section explicitly enumerates all ways that you can do that. Anything not listed does not establish HB:

"Natural" HB: If B runs 'after' A in the same thread (because within the confines of a single thread, ordering is well-defined), then obviously HB(A, B). In other words, int x = 5; x = 10; System.out.println(x); run on its own in one thread cannot print 5. It must print 10.
Thread interactions. HB(t.start(), first line in the started thread). Also, HB(last line in thread, t.join()).
synchronized. thread C exiting a synchronized block is HB relative to thread D entering a synchronized block afterwards if the sync blocks are on the same object reference. entering and exiting of sync blocks on the same referent have an ordering.
volatile interactions, but generally it's hard to know which one 'comes first' and which one 'comes second'. But some order will exist; one of them is HB relative to the other one.
A few more estoric things.
Of course, anything in the JVM core libs that uses one of the things in this list indirectly establishes HB just as well.

In particular, while there is no guarantee, all impls of System.out I know of establish HB relative to other sysout lines in some order. That makes 'trying to observe wonkiness due to lack of HB' difficult. Furthermore, a JVM is free not to 'use' the freedom to not sync up fields. So, observing "hey this code seems to run great!" does not mean your code actually "works". It may fail tomorrow or on different hardware; it's buggy and in a way you can't test. Painful.
Your code is broken
It establishes no HB. Therefore, the print statement in actor2 prints either 0 or 1. This is true even if you somehow know actor1() has already executed (because there is no HB(A, B) where A is x = 1 and B is System.out.println(x), the JVM does not have to 'transport' the update of the x field to the other thread; how much time has passed between the 2 statements is irrelevant).
As per JVM rules, it can't print anything else. 0, or 1. JVM does not allow sheared updates on int nor does it allow observing cruft that it was never set to.
A JVM can print 0 every tuesday and 1 every wednesday and that would be fine. It can print 0 always. That's fine. It can print 1 always. That's fine. It can print 1 always, unless the system is under heavy load, and then start printing 0 ocassionally. It might print 0 always, except once every 10 million times it prints a 1.
All fine.
The way to 'solve' this problem is not to play this game. You should never ever get into a situation where one thread has updated a field, another thread reads it, and no HB is established. Even if you think your code should be fine regardless of choice, the amount of situations your code can be in is a combinatory explosion, and it is untestable.

I would like to know if the CPU's MESI protocol, storeBuffer, and invalidate queue will cause visibility issues after thread A completes x=1 execution?

@qwee the JVM is not defined in those terms therefore your question cannot be answered like that. The JVM defines these issues in terms of Happens Before. The reason the JVM is specified that way is no doubt to ensure JVM can allow the CPU to use those things you mentioned, but, the JVM targets many platforms. Including platforms that don't have 'MESI' whatever that might be.

And ... the answer is that MESI, etc are irrelevant to the problem.  The issue will be that the JIT compiler is not inserting memory barriers BECAUSE the absence of HB relationships in the OP's code makes them unnecessary. (As far as the JLS is concerned ...)

The JMM is defined in terms of sequential consistent executions and for that the real time order isn't relevant. So the fact that there is a happens before edge between a write and read of a variable, doesn't mean that a read needs to see the most recent write; it only needs to see the most recent write before it in the memory order. For that, you need linearizability (sequential consistency + real time order).

@pveentjer I think you're saying 'this answer is correct' but I'm not quite sure. If it's missing something, I can try to fix it. But as far as I understand the JMM, everything I mentioned is correct and not oversimplified other than in obvious, stated ways (such as: The list of how to establish HB isn't complete).

As an addition, if a JVM's optimizer sees code like field = new TestJUC(); field.actor2(); and the field is not volatile, it can optimize it to the equivalent of field = new TestJUC(); System.out.println(0); using the predictable outcome, ignoring potential updates made by other threads. The CPU specific memory visibility is entirely irrelevant then.
